# Regarding the introduction of a controversial idea as a business plan

Tags: criminal-law, business, human-rights

I have a friend who knows someone who is busy broadening an entire businessplan. He already has a team of people who are willing to help him realise his plan. But it frightens me. The main idea of his plan is as follows: he wants to create a business that creates amfitheater and collosea around the world and let delinquents who have committed severe crimes fight eachother till the death like the gladiators in the ancient Rome. Specifically those people who are in death row all over the world. He also wants this to be realised a couple of weeks after the ending of the Game of Thrones serie because he thinks it forms a good link.

I thought it would never be realised because of all the human rights organizations like for instance amnesty international and also the basic human rights of each citizen on earth scripted in the United Nations Human Rights "document".

> My question is: "Can this business plan be realized and which barriers does the founder needs to go through before going worldwide?

Comment: Why would they fight to death, for what reward?

Comment: Stupid plan and would be illegal in the vast majority of countries, either directly or by censorship of such media.

Answer (score 1):

A minority of countries in the world authorize the death penalty. Fewer use it with any regularity. Those countries that do use the death penalty specify the manner in which it shall be carried out, often against a long standing cultural and historical and religious gloss. No country authorizes this form of the death penalty today.

Some of the main users of the death penalty are the U.S. (whose constitutional jurisprudence forbids this method of execution), many Islamic countries where cultural, religious and historical traditions favor different means of execution, and a few Asian countries, the dominant one of which is China.

A country would have to change its death penalty laws to do this, and while China is probably the country least wed by tradition to its methods of execution, I doubt that even China would agree to this business plan as it would be very costly for it in international affairs.